# Azure Firewall: How to translate Internet URL to Internal/Intranet URL?

Tags: azure, azure-private-link, azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

I have created the following Vnets

[image]

> `vnet-hub-poc-hubspoke` is the Hub Vnet

> and both the Vnets are peered as per the `HUB-SPOKE` model

[image]

[image]

> `vnet-hub-poc-hubspoke` being a Hub Vnet, it has `Azure firewall` configured

[image]

> both the Vnets are connected to `Azure Private DNS`

[image]

> `Azure Private DNS` has a record pointing to the VM deployed on the `vnet-prod-poc-hubspoke` Vnet

[image]

and I could access the `FQDN` within the internal network

[image]

after adding the below rule in `Azure Firewall`, I could access the website using the `firewall public IP`

[image]

Now, instead of `firewall public IP` I want to use the domain name like

> http://myfirstweb.private.landingzonedomain.com/ (for now, I have updated the hosts file in the client machine pointing to `firewall public IP`)

what should I do at the azure firewall level so that it would translate Internet URL to Internal/Intranet URL like

> http://myfirstweb.private.landingzonedomain.local/

Comment: I would recommend using an AppGW or Frontdoor in your hub vnet and Deny all inbound traffic on the Azure Firewall. This gives you more control, and you’ll be able to use custom domains and certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible, because you cannot assign a domain name to your Azure Firewall. What you could do is to create a DNS record at a domain name provider that translates a custom domain to your Azure firewall public IP.

Although I have seen people routing inbound traffic in their vnet, Azure firewall is mainly designed for controlling outbound traffic and traffic flowing between (peered) vnets. When you want to direct inbound traffic to a website or service inside your vnet, you can choose between:

- [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview)
- [Frontdoor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview)
- Combination of both

All the options above allow you to add custom domains and certificates. On the other hand, when you want to access a virtual machine through rdp or ssh, your main options are:

- [Bastion host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview) (i.e. jumpbox)
- [VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways)
- [Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cloud-shell/private-vnet)